# Smarty template and Javascript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty

I am using a smarty template and when I put this line of code in my tpl file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

It finds the wrong file. I have a file called jquery.js and when I click on jquery.cookie.js in my source file it brings up jquery.js

Is this related to smarty?

Seems weird that all of sudden they stopped working.

Comment: when I goto view the source of jquery.cookie.js it looks something is removing .cookie and viewing the file as jquery.js but still display the file name as jquery.cookie.js

Comment: I noticed that my modifier.auto_version adds .20140106 to my file, example style.css turned into style.20140106.css but when i view the source, its showing me style.css